# Excel web query returned no data no-vba

Tags: excel

I have a web query (Data tab -From Web). This is not getting pulled with VBA.

Is there a way to disable the error from popping up?

It pops up like once a day.

"Application.DisplayAlerts = False"

The above does not work. (I'm guessing because I am not pulling the web query with VBA).

Am I going to have to resort to using VBA to pull a query to stop the error?
Or is there a way to disable errors within Excel?

Comment: you should probably address the cause of the alert instead of just trying to suppress it

Comment: Well it is just unable to pull data from the site b/c the data has not changed. There is no real issue. I have it refreshing every 60 seconds, so there is bound to not have new data within the last 60 seconds. :) Thanks for the support though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to turn off Excel data refresh and do the whole lot through VBA. 
Go to Data, Properties and untick Refresh every x minutes.

Then in VBA try the following

```
Sub Refresh()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Refresh"

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I used this on my excel workbook when I kept on getting refresh data errors and it works a treat.
Hope this helps